# json single quotation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I want to send JSON data but in value single quotation error

I want this value, but in the value There are single quotes

```
 $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "canliAyarlari.aspx/dosyaYaz",
                    cache: false,                       
                    async:false,

                    data: {"veri:'1. takım kazanır ve maçta 3,5'tan fazla gol olur'}",

                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType:"json",
                    success: function (durum) {
                        alert(durum.d);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Hata");
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Send the normal ajax object insted: `data: {admin: 'foo', ...}`

Comment: JSON doesn't use single quotes, only double quotes, so it's simply invalid JSON, and can't be done, also the quotes needs to go aroung each key and each value, use a linter to check the JSON

Comment: I tried but it did not. You tell a more open please

Comment: @adeneo there is no JSON there at all actually

Comment: @zerkms - I know, but he's clearly trying to send JSON, as the contentType is set.

Comment: @user3625348 you currently have a syntax error: there is no pair for the opening `}`.

Comment: `data : '{"veri" : "1. takım kazanır ve maçta 3,5'tan fazla gol olur"}',`

Comment: ... or even `JSON.stringify()` (since then you wouldn't miss to escape a `'` :-) )

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need to construct a JSON string out of a JS object you always should use `JSON.stringify()`. That way it takes all the problems with proper encoding of all characters for you.

For your case it will look like:

```
...
data: JSON.stringify({
    veri: "1. takım kazanır ve maçta 3,5'tan fazla gol olur"
}),
...
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Note that with this, you're not sending the data in the [traditional encoding types a form would](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) but as JSON, which would cause most servers to recognize it as an http request with a plain text body.

Comment: @Pluto and as `adeneo` pointed out in the comments - according to the `contentType` seems like that's what exactly OP wants to do.

Comment: @user3625348 just check it as an answer then :-D